# Copy double data from a text file into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, double

I have a text file of 257 points like this

```
3.78135
2.84681
2.81403
2.54225
3.10854
  ...
```

and I would like to read this data and copy them into an array. With the help of similar answered question I wrote this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int max_read = 258;
double phi[max_read];
FILE *stream;
stream = fopen("namefile.txt", "r");

if (stream == NULL) {
  print ("! Cannot open file %sn", "namefile.txt\n"); 
  exit(1);
} else{
  int m = 0;
  while(m<max_read) {
    phi[m] = // But I still don't know how write the correct value into the array. 
    m++;
  }
}
```

I also would like to do this reading-coping procedure until the end of file.

Comment: Do you know about `scanf`? Do you know there is a [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read from a `FILE *`?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick i think.

```
if (stream == NULL) {
    fprint("! Cannot open file %sn", "namefile.txt\n");
    exit(1);
} else{
    int m = 0;
    while (fscanf(stream, "%lf\n", &phi[m])){
        m++;
    }
}
```